# django-audiofield no such file or directory when uploading new audio file from admin interface

Tags: python, django, audio

I am trying to implement the [django-audiofield](https://github.com/areski/django-audiofield) plugin with some success, but one major problem. I have everything working, as in the admin interface recognizes my new model with the audio field, but when I try to upload it with a new audio file it throws and error at me which I have not been able to debug.

This is the error page log.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://45.63.1.97/admin/website/musicpost/add/

Django Version: 1.8.4
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_cleanup',
 'pagedown',
 'website',
 'audiofield')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'audiofield.middleware.threadlocals.ThreadLocals')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  616.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1516.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  145.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1467.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
  1078.         obj.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  734.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  771.                                    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  201.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_audiofield-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/audiofield/fields.py" in _rename_audio
  222.                     self._convert_audio(dst_fullpath, instance, ext[1:4])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_audiofield-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/audiofield/fields.py" in _convert_audio
  140.             response = subprocess.Popen(command.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py" in __init__
  710.                                 errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py" in _execute_child
  1327.                 raise child_exception

Exception Type: OSError at /admin/website/musicpost/add/
Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is the code for my model.

```
# Music post model
class MusicPost (models.Model):
    # Creation time field
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # Updated time field
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # Body text for the post
    body = models.TextField()
    # Add the audio field to your model
    audio_file = AudioField(upload_to='/root/goodbyejuly/media', blank=True,
                            ext_whitelist=(".mp3", ".wav", ".ogg"),
                            help_text=("Allowed type - .mp3, .wav, .ogg"))
    # Add this method to your model
    def audio_file_player(self):
        """audio player tag for admin"""
        if self.audio_file:
            file_url = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + str(self.audio_file)
            player_string = '<ul class="playlist"><li style="width:250px;">\
            <a href="%s">%s</a></li></ul>' % (file_url, os.path.basename(self.audio_file.name))
            return player_string

    # Audio field settings
    audio_file_player.allow_tags = True
    audio_file_player.short_description = ('Audio file player')
```

This is how I am registering the model in the admin interface.

```
admin.site.register(MusicPost, MarkdownModelAdmin)
```

This is the markdown model admin widget which I am using for the body text, it has worked fine for me in the past.

```
# Admin interface override for text field markdown preview
class MarkdownModelAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Override specific model fields
    formfield_overrides = {
        # Override text fields to show markdown previews
        models.TextField: {'widget': AdminPagedownWidget },
    }
```

Can anyone help me fix my problem? If you need any more information I will provide it.

Comment: Do you have `soxi` installed? Looks like `django_audiofield` uses it for format conversion.

Comment: how did you solve your problem, I'm facing the same one..

Answer (score 0):

Like Alex mentioned, one solution is to install **soxi**. You can do so with the following commands (*my distro is ubuntu 14*).

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skellat/flow1
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-all

link to the complete guide is http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-sox-14-4-1-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-and-derivative-systems/